# How do combine multiple columns into one column such that column 2 starts at the end of column 1 using python?

Tags: python

I'm using pandas and I have a data frame with multiple columns like this:

```
Col1 CoL2 Col3
A      E    I
B      F    J
C      G    K
Nan    H    L
D      NaN
```

and so on..

How can I combine these columns into one so that it becomes:

```
New Col
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
```

I also need to get rid of any empty elements (the "NaN"s).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this using pandas? If so you should explicitly state that, otherwise this is confusing.

Comment: Yes I'm using pandas - sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df is original data frame, df_ where the code will append the values.

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=['New'])
for ii in df.columns:
    xtr = {'New':df[ii].to_list()}
    df_=df_.append(pd.DataFrame(xtr),ignore_index=True).dropna()
print(df_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate series together using `append()`, and `dropna()` to remove the NaNs.

```
df.Col1.append(df.Col2).append(df.Col3).dropna()
```